# Getting below issue in VS 2015 enterprise installation. VS2013 I already uninstalled. Only VS code and VS 2010 is there in my machine

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

Getting below issue in VS 2015 enterprise installation. VS2013 I already uninstalled. Only VS code and VS 2010 is there in my machine

[image]

Comment: Contact the IT department of your company. This is not something SO can help.

Comment: Got you. Thanks ...